# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'invalid' of undefined

Tags: angular

1. I am using nested FormGroup and in the html FormGroup is parent
   formGroup and skills is nested form, but on validation controls are
   not finding. can anyone help on this. Thanks in Advance.

   ```
   ngOnInit() {
       this.studentForm = new FormGroup({
         fullName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
         email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
         skills: new FormGroup({
           skillName: new FormControl(),
           ExperienceInYears: new FormControl(),
           Proficiency: new FormControl()

         })
       })


   html ---
   <div formGroupName='skills'>
             <div class="form-group">
               <label for="Email1">Skill Name</label>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName='skillName' placeholder="Skill Name">
               <div *ngIf="studentForm.controls['skills'].controls[skillName].invalid && (studentForm.controls['skills'].controls[skillName].dirty ||
   ```

   studentForm.controls['skills'].controls[skillName].touched)"
                     class="alert alert-danger">
                     
                       skill Name is required.

   ```
   validation is not working

   ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'invalid' of undefined

   can any one help
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer, error resolve but nested FormGroup validation is not working

Answer (score 2):

I guess you forgot to wrap `skillName` in quotes:

```
studentForm.controls['skills'].controls[skillName]
                                            \/
                                       ['skillName']
```

Comment: for that `\/` symbol!

Comment: Thanks for your Answer, error resolve but nested   FormGroup validation is not working

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in stackblitz?

Comment: nested FormGroup validation is not working .. please help

Comment: Add Validators.required to skillName control. It is not required in your form definition

Comment: @user3036781 Please check this example https://ng-run.com/edit/A8MjTyOZrbcbUUqnb6rk